# Struts2 - validation of instance of another class inside Action class

Tags: struts2

I have a Action class with few fields (String, int etc) + instance of User class (userBean)  inside it. If I want to validate field values I can do it using validation framework, but if I want to validate "userBean.username" from User class how can I do that using validation framework?

Tried below but did not work

```
<field name="userBean.username">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
      <param name="trim">true</param>
      <message key="errors.required" />
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate the inputs of a form, you can't use it this way. The validation framework kicks in before the action treats the request (see [interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptors.html)), that's why you can't do what you're doing. So regarding your question, you need to put the actual field name which matches your username and then set its value to your UserBean instance.

If you need more infos, just check the official doc.